# Repeat Labels in Pivot Tables (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

Currently, I am working on a code that iterates through three sheets of data that are identical in formatting and then creates three pivot tables (one for each sheet) that has an identical format.  I want to toggle the Repeat Labels format on within the VBA code, but cannot seem to do it.  The following link is one that I found that I have tried, but to no success: http://excelpivots.com/pivot/repeat_item_labels/

I would paste my code, but it is rather long.  The gist of what I tried was putting:

```
For each PField in PTable

    If PField.Orientation = xlRowField Then PField.RepeatLabels = True

Next PField
```

within the loop that creates the three pivot tables.  However, it throws error 438.

I did some further research and found this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198076.aspx), but am not sure how to use it.

Comment: I think it should be `For each PField in PTable.PivotFields`

Comment: Thanks! You're the best.  Still doesn't do what I want schematically, but at least there are no errors.

Comment: can you post-up an image of what the desired output should be ?